# Geometry Question

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

anyone can help me with this question:
in the triangle, ABC below points A and C are fixed however point B moves in time by a constant increment h, if you know α angle and segment AB, calculate the segments AB', AB''.

[image: pic]

Comment: I think you need 3 components of a triangle to solve it. I doubt one side and one angle is enough to compute the rest..

Comment: let's say that in the standard case AC=BC

Comment: This will clarify the question more: you can think of it as a triangle with one of vertices dilation, so I'm planning to use (h) increments, to measure the increasing in AB', AB'' According to AB....but I don't know how??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Find $\angle ABC$ in terms of $\alpha$.

**Added:-** By angle sum of triangle, $\beta = 90^ - 0.5\alpha$.

[image]

2) Find AC by sine law. Then, BC is known.

**Added:-** Let AB be k units, a known quantity.  $AC = \dfrac {k \sin \beta}{\sin \alpha}$. Then, $BC = AC$.

3) AB’ can be found by applying cosine law.

**Added:-** In $\triangle ACB’$,  $AB’ = \sqrt {(h + AC)^2 + (AC)^2 – 2(h + AC)(AC) \cos \alpha}$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Could you give an example?? and maybe this will clarify the question more: you can think of it as a triangle with one of vertices dilation, so I'm planning to use (h) increments, to measure the increasing in AB', AB'' According to AB....but I don't know how??

Comment: @Ala'Alobeidyeen See added.

Comment: Thank you, I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

(That's my first answer here)

Usually the angle $\alpha$ is next to the point $A$ and the angle $\gamma$ is next to the point $C$. 

 So I'll call the given angle $\gamma$ instead of $\alpha$.

 Further more I'll define the points
$$ B_n :=
\begin{cases}
B'\ ,  & \text{if $n$ is 1} \\
B'', & \text{if $n$ is 2.}
\end{cases} $$.

I'll give you a short OVERVIEW about how to calculate the desired segments $\overline{A B'}$ and $\overline{A B''}$:

1. Calculate the altitude $h_a$ to the side $\overline{BC}$.

    Let's call the intersection of $h_a$ and $\overline{BC}$: $$H_a := h_a \cap \overline{BC}$$
2. Calcualte the length of $\overline{H_a B}$.
3. Calcualte the length of $\overline{H_a B_n}$.
4. Calcualte the length of $\overline{A B_n}$.

DETAILS:

1. Calculate $h_a$ by applying the 'Law of sines' to the triangle $\triangle AH_aC$:
   $$
     \begin{align}
       \frac{h_a}{\sin \gamma} & = \frac{\overline{AC}}{\sin \frac \pi 2}
       \tag{$\sin \frac \pi 2 = 1$}
       \\ 
       \frac{h_a}{\sin \gamma} & = \overline{AC}
       \tag{multiply with $\sin \gamma$}
       \\
       h_a & = \overline{AC} \cdot \sin \gamma
     \end{align}
   $$
2. Calcualte the length of $\overline{H_a B}$ by applying the Pythagorean theorem on the triangle $\triangle H_a A B$:
   $$ \begin{align}
       \overline{H_a B}^2 & = \overline{AB}^2 - h_a^2        \tag{2a} \\
       \overline{H_a B}   & = \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 - h_a^2} \tag{2b} 
       \end{align}
     $$
3. Calcualte the length of $\overline{H_a B_n}$:
   $$
     \begin{align}
       \overline{H_a B_n} & = \overline{H_a B} + \overline{B B_n} \\
                          & = \overline{H_a B} + n \cdot h
     \end{align}
   $$
4. Calcualte the length of $\overline{A B_n}$ by applying the Pythagorean theorem on the triangle $\triangle B_n H_a A$:
   $$
   \begin{align}
     \overline{A B_n} & = \sqrt{h_a^2 + \overline{H_a B_n}^2} \tag{apply step 3} \\
       & = \sqrt{h_a^2 + \left(\overline{H_a B} + n \cdot h\right)^2} \\
       & = \sqrt{h_a^2 + \overline{H_a B}^2 + 2 n h \overline{H_a B} + n^2 h^2} \tag{apply steps 2a and 2b} \\
       & = \sqrt{h_a^2 + \overline{AB}^2 - h_a^2 + 2 n h \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 - h_a^2} + n^2 h^2} \tag{simplify} \\
       & = \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 + 2 n h \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 - h_a^2} + n^2 h^2} \tag{apply step 1} \\
       & = \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 + 2 n h \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 - \overline{AC}^2 (\sin \gamma) ^2} + n^2 h^2} \\
   \end{align}
     $$

   4a. Calculate Length of $\overline{A B'}$ by setting $n = 1$:
   $$ \overline{A B'} = \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 + 2 h \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 - \overline{AC}^2 (\sin \gamma) ^2} + h^2} $$
   4b. Calculate Length of $\overline{A B''}$ by setting $n = 2$:
   $$ \overline{A B'} = \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 + 4 h \sqrt{\overline{AB}^2 - \overline{AC}^2 (\sin \gamma) ^2} + 4h^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\overline{AB}=r$, $\overline{AC}=\overline{BC}=s$, and $\overline{BB'}=x$. Then by the law of cosines,
$$r^2 = s^2 + s^2 - 2s^2\cos\alpha\quad\Rightarrow\quad
    s = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2-2\cos\alpha}}.$$
Next, consider $\triangle AB'C$. There,
$$\overline{AB'} = s^2 + (s+x)^2 - 2s(s+x)\cos\alpha.$$
Substitute the value of $s$ above into this equation and simplify, giving
$$\overline{AB'} = r^2 + x^2 + r x \sqrt{2 - 2 \cos\alpha}.$$
Then $AB'$ and $AB''$ in your figure can be calculated by setting $x=h$ and $x=2h$.